# Unexpected 404 error on get request for a local file - axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, get

I have a `data.json` file in my computer that I am trying to access.

Below is my folder structure

```
> library-project
  > data
      data.json
  > src
    > pages
      index.tsx
```

index.tsx

```js
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from "axios";

export default function FeaturedBooks() {
  const getBooks = () => {
    axios
      .get("data/data.json")
      .then((res: AxiosResponse) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err: AxiosError) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={getBooks}>Get Books</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Message in console -
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I am pretty sure my file path is correct. I don't understand why I am getting a 404. I also tried to disable my computer's firewall. It didn't improve anything.

I am not sure how to fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can just import the data in the component. Why do you need to use axios here?

Comment: I am trying to read a .json file not a JSON object. Don't you need axios to read .json files?

Comment: I don't think so. you can import the json file in the component. If you still want to use axios then you need to move the data directory in public folder.

Comment: you can import like this: import data from '../data/data.json'; and use data in the component.

Comment: @CodeThing Thank you! I tried both methods. It finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can either import the json file in the component like this

```
import data from '../data/data.json';
```

Or if you want to use axios then you need to move the data directory in public folder